# Spring Constant - Waves

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, spring

I tried to prove that for the same length of spring , a one dimensional wave that moves faster in spring 2 than spring 1, its spring constant will be lower than the spring constant of spring 1.

That's the begining of the proof I tried to make:

$$w = \sqrt{\frac km} = 2π \cdot \nu$$

$$\nu = \frac{1}{2π} \cdot \sqrt{\frac km}$$

$$k = m \cdot \nu^ 2 \cdot 4π ^ 2$$

What am I missing?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. What is moving? Is there a weight attached to a spring, and the weight is moving? Or is the spring propagating longitudinal waves? Or is the spring propagating transverse waves? What is $m$?

Comment: http://www.physics-chemistry-interactive-flash-animation.com/mechanics_forces_gravitation_energy_interactive/progressive_longitudinal_wave_pulse_spring.htm

Comment: as you can watch here , It was requsted to find out which spring has bigger spring constant using equations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a solid rod which is axially compressed and has mass $m=\rho A \ell$. The spring rate of the rod is $k=\frac{E A}{\ell}$ and the wave speed $\nu^2 = \frac{E}{\rho}$

All of these combined gives us $ m = \frac{E}{\nu^2} \frac{k \ell}{E} \ell = \frac{k \ell^2}{\nu^2}$

$$ k = m \frac{\nu^2}{\ell^2} $$

So for the same length $\ell$ the higher the wave speed the higher the stiffness. You can extend this to helical springs, but end results are the same.

Comment: I just don't understand why knowing the fact that k is affected by mass , and the fact that for greater mass the velocity of the wave is lower, how you can still be sure that the spring with the greater mass has greater spring constant. I tried to find something that is constant for both situations , greater mass or lower mass , and it will replace the velocity.

Comment: No $\nu$ is not affected by mass. $\nu$ is constant for the same material. It is the speed of sound for that material. It depends on the modulus of elasticity $E$ and the density $\rho$.